# Join Table with a CASE statement and based on the CASE, then SELECT a MAX value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to join a table on 4 conditions, of which 2 are very straightforward and 2 other conditions which are more difficult.

The first two:

`PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.ContractID` = `CUSTAMOUNTREPORTTABLE.ContractID`
`PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.DATAAREAID` = `CUSTAMOUNTREPORTTABLE.DATAAREAID`

The second two:

Only if the `FROMDATE` from Table `PMCCONTRACTSTATUS` is lower then the `PERIODSTART` in Table `CUSTAMOUNTREPORTTABLE` 
`AND` only if that is the case `THEN` Take the highest `RowNumber`. EDIT: Because I want to JOIN the `[STATUS]` that is the CLOSEST to the `PERIODSTART`.

EDIT: I Made a sample dataset which only includes the necessary parts to solve the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG2 (
    ContractID nvarchar(20)
    ,[Status] int
    ,FromDate date
    ,RowNumber int
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTAMOUNTREPORTTABLE2 (
    ContractID nvarchar(20)
    ,PERIODSTART date
);

INSERT INTO PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG2 
(ContractID, [Status], FromDate, RowNumber)
VALUES
    ('HC1','1','01-01-2019','1'),
    ('HC1','2','01-02-2019','2'),
    ('HC1','1','01-04-2019','3'),
    ('HC2','1','01-04-2019','1'),
    ('HC2','2','01-05-2019','2'),
    ('HC3','4','01-01-2019','1'),
    ('HC3','2','01-02-2019','2'),
    ('HC3','1','01-07-2019','3'),
    ('HC3','2','01-09-2019','4'),
    ('HC4','2','01-08-2019','1'),
    ('HC4','3','01-07-2019','2'),
    ('HC5','1','01-02-2019','1');

INSERT INTO CUSTAMOUNTREPORTTABLE2
(ContractID, PERIODSTART)
VALUES
    ('HC1','01-01-2019'),
    ('HC2','01-01-2019'),
    ('HC3','01-01-2019'),
    ('HC5','01-01-2019'),
    ('HC1','01-02-2019'),
    ('HC3','01-02-2019'),
    ('HC5','01-02-2019'),
    ('HC1','01-03-2019'),
    ('HC3','01-03-2019'),
    ('HC5','01-03-2019'),
    ('HC1','01-04-2019'),
    ('HC2','01-04-2019'),
    ('HC3','01-04-2019'),
    ('HC5','01-04-2019'),
    ('HC1','01-05-2019'),
    ('HC2','01-05-2019'),
    ('HC3','01-05-2019'),
    ('HC5','01-05-2019');

SELECT * FROM PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG2
SELECT * FROM CUSTAMOUNTREPORTTABLE2
```

I try with the following query to join the PMCCONTRACTSTATUS Table, I know the logic behind the join, but I fail to write a JOIN that combines a CASE WHEN + SELECT statement.

```
;WITH PMCCONTRACTSTATUS AS
(
SELECT
    CONTRACTID
    ,[STATUS]
    ,FROMDATE
    ,DATAAREAID
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONTRACTID ORDER BY FROMDATE ASC) RN
FROM PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG
WHERE [STATUS] <> 10 OR [STATUS] <> 5
)
SELECT 
    CART.CONTRACTID
    ,PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.CONTRACTID
    ,CART.ACCOUNTNUM
    ,CART.AMOUNTMSTTOTAL
    ,CART.PERIODSTART
    ,PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.FROMDATE
    ,CART.PERIODEND
    ,CART.NAME
    ,CART.PMCCONTRACTSTATUSWEIGHTED
    ,PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.[STATUS]
FROM CUSTAMOUNTREPORTTABLE CART
LEFT JOIN PMCCONTRACTSTATUS
    ON PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.CONTRACTID = CART.CONTRACTID
    AND PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.DATAAREAID = CART.DATAAREAID
    /*AND CASE WHEN PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.FROMDATE <= CART.PERIODSTART 
        THEN (SELECT MAX(PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.RN) FROM PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG)*/
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: Are you sure you just want to `PARTITION BY CONTRACTID` and not also `DATAAREAID` ? From my understanding you're trying to get the ContractStatusLog with the closest possible StartDate compared to the PeriodStart (with same contract and data area) ? Am I right ?

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying indeed. The DataAreaID is a column that in the PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG always has the value of '1', so it's not so interesting in this case. But I am going to include a Dataset to this question to make it easier to answer.

Comment: Included the sample Dataset, copy-paste ready for SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based from my understanding, maybe some parts are missing :

First I try to join with your 3 first conditions in a CTE. And then I create a `ROW_NUMBER()` based on the `DATEDIFF` between your 2 dates.

Tell me if it helps :

```
;WITH 
CTE AS (
SELECT 
    CART.CONTRACTID
    ,CART.ACCOUNTNUM
    ,CART.AMOUNTMSTTOTAL
    ,CART.PERIODSTART
    ,PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.FROMDATE
    ,CART.PERIODEND
    ,CART.NAME
    ,CART.PMCCONTRACTSTATUSWEIGHTED
    ,PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.[STATUS]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CART.CONTRACTID,CART.DATAAREAID ORDER BY DATEDIFF(second,FROMDATE,PERIODSTART) ASC) RN
FROM CUSTAMOUNTREPORTTABLE CART
LEFT JOIN PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG
    ON PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.CONTRACTID = CART.CONTRACTID
    AND PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.DATAAREAID = CART.DATAAREAID
    AND PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.FROMDATE <= CART.PERIODSTART 
WHERE [STATUS] NOT IN (5,10)
)
SELECT 
    CONTRACTID
    ,ACCOUNTNUM
    ,AMOUNTMSTTOTAL
    ,PERIODSTART
    ,FROMDATE
    ,PERIODEND
    ,NAME
    ,PMCCONTRACTSTATUSWEIGHTED
    ,[STATUS]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: This didn't work somehow. What I immediately noticed is that my 165100 rows decreased to 21000 rows. I did include a dataset now to make it replicable.

Comment: After tweeking this, this Query works like a charm. It works better than the OUTER APPLY suggestion from someone else, since OUTER APPLY took 2 hours to complete the query, and this completed within 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use OUTER APPLY instead of LEFT JOIN

```
;WITH PMCCONTRACTSTATUS AS
(
SELECT
    CONTRACTID
    ,[STATUS]
    ,FROMDATE
    ,DATAAREAID
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONTRACTID ORDER BY FROMDATE ASC) RN
FROM PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG
WHERE [STATUS] <> 10 OR [STATUS] <> 5
)
SELECT 
    CART.CONTRACTID
    ,PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.CONTRACTID
    ,CART.ACCOUNTNUM
    ,CART.AMOUNTMSTTOTAL
    ,CART.PERIODSTART
    ,MAX_PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.FROMDATE
    ,CART.PERIODEND
    ,CART.NAME
    ,CART.PMCCONTRACTSTATUSWEIGHTED
    ,MAX_PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.[STATUS]
FROM CUSTAMOUNTREPORTTABLE CART
OUTER APPLY (select top 1 *
            from PMCCONTRACTSTATUS
            where PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.CONTRACTID = CART.CONTRACTID
                    AND PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.DATAAREAID = CART.DATAAREAID
                    AND PMCCONTRACTSTATUS.FROMDATE <= CART.PERIODSTART
                    ORDER BY PMCCONTRACTSTATUSLOG.RN DESC) as MAX_PMCCONTRACTSTATUS
```